# 15A 250V Extension Cord, but the voltage rating in my country is 220... What does that mean?

Tags: voltage

Written on my Extension Cord: 15A 250V, but the voltage rating in my country is 220... What does that mean?

Comment: It means you're safe.

Comment: It says the allowable maximum voltage and current ratings. Don't worry.

Comment: It really means that this question doesn't belong here.

Comment: You're still 30 V below the speed limit, so the Voltage Police won't write you a ticket.

Answer (score 2):

It means you're fine. As long as the rating of the cord (250V) exceeds the actual voltage (220V), there's nothing to worry about.

The ratings of the extension cord are *maximum* values that should never be exceeded. It will work fine for any voltage less than 250V and for any load current that is less than 15A.